# MacBook Pro wakes up every two hours while lid is closed

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro 2010 and it has been waking up every two hours while the lid is closed. Even after a hard drive replacement and upgrading from OS X Mountain Lion to OS X El Captain.

```
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: hibernate image path: /var/vm/sleepimage
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: efi pagecount 125
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall(preflight 1) start
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall time: 617 ms
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: pages 2012211, wire 469243, act 911864, inact 3220, cleaned 0 spec 25, zf 87386, throt 0, compr 144649, xpmapped 40000
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: could discard act 28340 inact 258478 purgeable 37978 spec 71028 cleaned 0
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: WARNING: hibernate_page_list_setall skipped 23239 xpmapped pages
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall preflight pageCount 1616387 est comp 45 setfile 3222274048 min 4294967296
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: kern_open_file_for_direct_io(0)
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: kern_open_file_for_direct_io took 24 ms
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: Opened file /var/vm/sleepimage, size 4294967296, extents 6, maxio 2000000 ssd 0
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: polled file major 1, minor 0, blocksize 4096, pollers 5
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: hibernate_alloc_pages act 945070, inact 382196, anon 130807, throt 0, spec 71053, wire 487215, wireinit 26443
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: hibernate_setup(0) took 0 ms
15.10.16 12:40:06,000 kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall(preflight 0) start
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall time: 715 ms
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: pages 2014851, wire 471883, act 913851, inact 41233, cleaned 0 spec 25, zf 87386, throt 0, compr 144649, xpmapped 40000
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: could discard act 26353 inact 220465 purgeable 37978 spec 71028 cleaned 0
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: WARNING: hibernate_page_list_setall skipped 23242 xpmapped pages
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall found pageCount 1659027
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: IOHibernatePollerOpen, ml_get_interrupts_enabled 0
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: IOHibernatePollerOpen(0)
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: encryptStart 14050
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: bitmap_size 0x3f770, previewSize 0x3020, writing 1658737 pages @ 0x567e0
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: encryptEnd f0bf400
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: image1Size 0x1f13b000, encryptStart1 0x14050, End1 0xf0bf400
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: encryptStart 1f13b000
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: encryptEnd ba7d4000
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: PMStats: Hibernate write took 23694 ms
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: all time: 23694 ms, comp bytes: 6794534912 time: 6254 ms 1036 Mb/s, crypt bytes: 2859746224 time: 3860 ms 706 Mb/s, 
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: image 3128770560 (72%), uncompressed 6794534912 (610246), compressed 3115659042 (45%), sum1 568f195d, sum2 f72a81b2
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: svPageCount 27264, zvPageCount 151246, wiredPagesEncrypted 331855, wiredPagesClear 139823, dirtyPagesEncrypted 1187144
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: hibernate_write_image done(0)
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: sleep
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: Wake reason: RTC (Alarm)
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: RTC: Maintenance 2016/10/15 11:40:02, sleep 2016/10/15 09:40:31
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: Previous sleep cause: 5
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 syslogd[40]: ASL Sender Statistics
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link DOWN virtIf = 0
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: Got incomplete channel sequence length 0, should be 16
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: Got incomplete channel sequence length 0, should be 16
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
15.10.16 14:40:03,195 symptomsd[192]: -[NetworkAnalyticsEngine _writeJournalRecord:fromCellFingerprint:key:atLOI:ofKind:lqm:isFaulty:] Hashing of the primary key failed. Dropping the journal record.
15.10.16 14:40:03,000 kernel[0]: in6_unlink_ifa: IPv6 address 0xe1ccddcc04c9f381 has no prefix
15.10.16 14:40:03,423 UserEventAgent[41]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Inactive
15.10.16 14:40:03,824 cdpd[66067]: Saw change in network reachability (isReachable=0)
15.10.16 14:40:03,836 symptomsd[192]: __73-[NetworkAnalyticsEngine observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]_block_invoke unexpected switch value 2
15.10.16 14:40:03,838 netbiosd[82956]: network_reachability_changed : network is not reachable, netbiosd is shutting down
15.10.16 14:40:05,463 configd[49]: network changed: v4(en1-:192.168.1.69) DNS- Proxy-
15.10.16 14:40:07,000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: f0:79:59:78:c2:ec  MAC AUTH succeeded
15.10.16 14:40:07,000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
15.10.16 14:40:07,000 kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on en1
15.10.16 14:40:07,000 kernel[0]: Got incomplete channel sequence length 0, should be 16
15.10.16 14:40:07,000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to f0:79:59:78:c2:ec
15.10.16 14:40:07,000 kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 36,+1
15.10.16 14:40:07,000 kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
15.10.16 14:40:07,213 symptomsd[192]: -[NetworkAnalyticsEngine _writeJournalRecord:fromCellFingerprint:key:atLOI:ofKind:lqm:isFaulty:] Hashing of the primary key failed. Dropping the journal record.
15.10.16 14:40:07,000 kernel[0]: Unexpected payload found for message 9, dataLen 0
15.10.16 14:40:08,000 kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
15.10.16 14:40:10,808 UserEventAgent[41]: Captive: [CNInfoNetworkActive:1748] en1: SSID 'FREE_CHILD_PORN' making interface primary (cache indicates network not captive)
15.10.16 14:40:10,808 configd[49]: network changed: DNS* Proxy
15.10.16 14:40:10,809 UserEventAgent[41]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Evaluating
15.10.16 14:40:10,809 UserEventAgent[41]: Captive: en1: Not probing 'FREE_CHILD_PORN' (cache indicates not captive)
15.10.16 14:40:10,809 UserEventAgent[41]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Authenticated
15.10.16 14:40:10,816 configd[49]: network changed: v4(en1!:192.168.1.69) DNS+ Proxy+ SMB
15.10.16 14:40:11,409 cdpd[66067]: Saw change in network reachability (isReachable=2)
15.10.16 14:40:11,425 symptomsd[192]: __73-[NetworkAnalyticsEngine observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]_block_invoke unexpected switch value 2
15.10.16 14:40:15,358 tccd[62457]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.modifydb
15.10.16 14:40:15,361 tccd[62457]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.modifydb
15.10.16 14:40:15,364 tccd[62457]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.modifydb
15.10.16 14:40:15,612 sandboxd[62463]: ([62457]) tccd(62457) deny mach-lookup com.apple.lsd.modifydb
15.10.16 14:40:15,645 sandboxd[62463]: ([62457]) tccd(62457) deny mach-lookup com.apple.lsd.modifydb
15.10.16 14:40:15,653 sandboxd[62463]: ([62457]) tccd(62457) deny mach-lookup com.apple.lsd.modifydb
15.10.16 14:40:55,828 mDNSResponder[88]: DHCPWakeTime: SCDynamicStoreCopyDHCPInfo index 0 failed CFDateRef start 0000000000000000 CFDataRef lease 0000000000000000 CFDataGetLength(lease) 0
15.10.16 14:40:57,000 kernel[0]: PM response took 1978 ms (50, powerd)
15.10.16 14:40:57,000 kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep
```

Does anyone know why and how to disable this?

Comment: Mac OS have this thing called ["Power Nap"](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT204032). Make sure you've disabled it.

Comment: @ZackTitan, turned it off now. I'll check the Journal after next time I put it sleep.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun, I guess it worked. Thanks. You may repost your comment as an answer, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS have this thing called "[Power Nap](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT204032)". Make sure you've disabled it.